# C# Web app can't download XML documents

Tags: c#, xml, download, webclient

If I use the following code in a C# console app (using Visual Studio), it works outright.

```
string xmlURL = "http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/index.xml";
string xml;
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    //client.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, */*;q=0.1";
    //client.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; de; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12";
    xml = client.DownloadString(xmlURL);
}
Console.WriteLine(xml);
```

If I try to use the exact same code in a web app, it consistently fails with a "could not connect to server" error.  I have tried it with, and without the .Accept and .UserAgent headers.  I have tried using multiple different sites and XML downloads.

It was suggested that maybe IE itself was blocking access, but if I directly copy the URL into IE, it displays the XML without prompts or problems.  I'm not sure it's even relevent since IE isn't used by the console app.

What else can I check/try?

Comment: Much more information needed here: What kind of WebApp do you have? In what environment are you using that? Is it implemented in IIS using ASP.NET or is it a stand-alone web-service? Maybe some firewall/security-policy issues?

Comment: Probably a permissions issue? Can you try to run the application as administrator or simply run visual studio as administrator to debug? Check your internet firewall configurations also (maybe turn them off just to debug)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  Since we are behind a proxy, I needed to add the following:

```
System.Net.WebProxy wp = new System.Net.WebProxy("proxyserver:80");
client.Proxy = wp;
```

Thank you, Patrik, for your interest in assisting.